# Insert value from one table to another by changing the flag

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have to insert value from one table to another table which both having two fields first field name is ID and and second field name is Flag.

While inserting if the ID value already exists in any of the destination table rows it will insert the new row in source table as same ID and Flag as NEW

if the ID value is not matching in any of the destination table rows it will insert row as ID and Flag as OLD.

For example (from comment below):

```
Table 1
-------- 
A O 
B O 
C O 

Table 2 
A N 
B N 
D N 

After Insert 
------------ 
A N 
B N 
C n 
A N 
B N 
D N
```

Comment: Do you mean if there's two tables take the rows from the first table and try to insert them into the second. If the ID exists in the second table flag it as NEW but if the ID doesn't exist in the second table flag it as OLD?

Comment: Table 1
--------
A O
B O
C O

Table 2
A N
B N
D N

After Insert
------------
A N
B N
C n
A N
B N
D N

Comment: @Jaison, I copied the above into the original question for readability. Still not sure I follow you though...

Answer (score 2):

If I follow you correctly, given the following

```
Source Table

ID  |  Flag
-----------
1      NULL  
2      NULL
3      NULL


Dest Table

ID  |  Flag
-----------
1      NULL
```

You want to insert records from `Source` into `Dest`.

- If the `ID` already exists in `Dest`, insert the `ID` into `Source` with a `flag` of ***NEW***
- If the `ID` does not exist in `Dest`, insert the `ID` into `Dest` with a `flag` of ***OLD***

---

First get the `ID`s that exist in both `Dest` and `Source` and insert ***NEW*** records into `Source`

```
    INSERT INTO Source (ID, Flag)
SELECT 
    s.ID, 'NEW'
FROM
    Source s
INNER JOIN
    Dest d
    ON d.ID = s.ID
```

then get the `ID`s that don't exist in `Dest` but exist in `Source` and insert ***OLD*** records into `Dest`

```
    INSERT INTO Dest (ID, Flag)
SELECT 
    s.ID, 'OLD'
FROM
    Source s
LEFT JOIN
    Dest d
    ON d.ID = s.ID
WHERE
    d.ID IS NULL
```

This results in

```
Source Table

ID    |     Flag
----------- ----
1           NULL
2           NULL
3           NULL
1           NEW

Dest Table

ID    |     Flag
----------- ----
1           NULL
2           OLD
3           OLD
```

Is that what you were looking for?

I have to be honest and say that this doesn't feel like a nice way to be doing things, for example, I think it would be better to update records that you already have in the tables rather than insert new ones with the same `ID`, although I don't know what you're trying to achieve or what keys you have on the tables (if any). If you could provide more info, I may be able to help further.